# Psych argument error when parsing YAML in Ruby after upgrading Bundler

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

I've just upgraded to Bundler 1.1 from 1.0. All my code that works previously now breaks with the following error:

```
~/.gem/gems/psych-1.3.2/lib/psych.rb:203:in `parse': wrong number of arguments(2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
  from ~/.gem/gems/psych-1.3.2/lib/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
  from ~/.gem/gems/psych-1.3.2/lib/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
  from ~/.gem/gems/psych-1.3.2/lib/psych.rb:127:in `load'
```

Is there someway to fix this? All I'm doing is calling `YAML.load`

Comment: Well, what arguments are you passing it?

Comment: I'm not passing any arguments specifically to Psych. I'm passing a YAML string to YAML.load and getting an error in Psych. As I said this code worked fine until I updated bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a fix but I've found I can remove psych as the YAML parser using:

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

Do this before calling:

```
YAML.load
```

I've opened [an issue on the psych project](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/61).

**UPDATE**: Problem seems to be related to the version of Ruby I was using. Updating my Ruby version fixed this. See the above issue on Psych.